# How to share music through DAAP using Rhythmbox?

Tags: 11.04, rhythmbox, daap

I have enabled DAAP plugin in Rhythmbox, ticked the "Share my music" option, but no DAAP server shows up in my other clients (android and another PC). Am I missing something, like firewall configurations, router configurations, etc?

I can talk to people over Bonjour, so I guess avahi/zeroconf is running properly.

Comment: Maybe a firewall blocks DAAP?

Comment: is there any more detail you can add to this question? It's kind of vague and ambiguous at the moment

Comment: @Stefano I had to roll back your title change, it was awful and meaningless. But now the question has a few more details.

Comment: Yes it is running. See my own answer for a facepalm.

Comment: @barraponto heh, thanks for that :-D I'd still suggest you change the title. you're not asking How to share music, you already know how to do this, but it's not working right (thinking about Google)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing else needs to be done. Rhythmbox DAAP works as soon as the plugin is enabled and the "Share my music" option is enabled in the plugin configuration.

However, your client MUST BE IN THE SAME NETWORK AS THE SERVER. This is, of course, a no brainer, but I just got tricked from the several networks available at my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

The only other "gotcha" with Rhythmbox Daap is that you have to be logged on to the Ubuntu computer and Rhythmbox must be running.

Comment: Does that mean that different users on the same computer cannot share their music folder this way ? I tried (both user sessions opened, same for rhythmbox) and it doesn't seem to work. I still haven't figured out then if what I want is possible with rhythmbox...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem at in Ubuntu 12.04. It looks like Rhythmbox only binds to the IPv6 interface, if IPv6 is enabled. This means that the music playing device must be talking IPv6. Which most of them don't.

Unfourtunately is the daap-server advertised for both ipv4 and ipv6.

Comment: While IPv6 does seem to be used it shouldn't be a problem. VLC, Rhythmbox can see the share.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the plugin is on, avahi-browser shows the DAAP services, and if you're running GNOME shell, make sure the media-sharing is enabled.

Your local firewall can also get in the way, use `netstat -tlnp` and make sure the listening ports for rhythmbox are open (or disable firewall if you're comfortable with that).